Integration of $\sin^2(\frac{\pi x}{a})(1-\frac{x}{a})$
The above integration is to be found between the limits $0$ to $\frac{a}{2}$.
This integrand I came across while solving perturbation theory in qm.
The answer should be $\frac{a}{4}$ but I'm getting a term with $\pi^2$.

Please use Latex and show your work

@pri is the integrand correct after the edit?

The integration limits has to be $0$ and $a$ to get $a/4$ here.

The answer is not $\frac{a}{4}$:
$$\begin{align*}\int_0^{\frac{a}{2}}{\sin ^2\left( \frac{\pi x}{a} \right) \left( 1-\frac{x}{a} \right) \mathrm{d}x}=&\int_0^{\frac{a}{2}}{\sin ^2\left( \frac{\pi x}{a} \right) \mathrm{d}x}-\int_0^{\frac{a}{2}}{\frac{x}{a}\sin ^2\left( \frac{\pi x}{a} \right) \mathrm{d}x}\\=&\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\frac{a}{2}}{\left( \sin ^2\left( \frac{\pi x}{a} \right) +\sin ^2\left( \frac{\pi \left( x-\frac{a}{2} \right)}{a} \right) \right) \mathrm{d}x}-\int_0^{\frac{a}{2}}{\frac{x}{a}\sin ^2\left( \frac{\pi x}{a} \right) \mathrm{d}x}\\=&\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\frac{a}{2}}{\left( \sin ^2\left( \frac{\pi x}{a} \right) +\cos ^2\left( \frac{\pi x}{a} \right) \right) \mathrm{d}x}-\int_0^{\frac{a}{2}}{\frac{x}{a}\sin ^2\left( \frac{\pi x}{a} \right) \mathrm{d}x}\\=&\frac{a}{4}-\int_0^{\frac{a}{2}}{\frac{x}{a}\sin ^2\left( \frac{\pi x}{a} \right) \mathrm{d}x}\\<&\frac{a}{4}\end{align*}$$

Here is how to do the integral with limits $0$ to $a$, which is most possibly what was intended (as stated, the integral is not $a/4$ as the other answer proves).
Let $$I=\int_0^a\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi x}{a}\right)\left(1-\frac xa\right)\,\mathrm dx$$
It is very natural to make the substitution $u=x/a$.
$$I=a\int_0^1\sin^2(\pi u)(1-u)\,\mathrm du$$
Then, do $v=1-u$.
$$I=a\int_0^1v\sin^2(\pi v)\,\mathrm dv$$
You should be able to get $a/4$ using integration by parts from here.
Hope this helps. :)
